# How do I exclude password fields from validation during record update? (Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.9.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, conditional-statements

I have a form which permits updating of a user record.  It contains fields for :password and :password_confirmation but I do **not** want validation to run on them if an encrypted password is already stored in the database.

The fields from the view file:

```
<%= f.password_field :password %>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :label => 'Confirm Password' %>
```

In searching the internet, I found this bit of code, which I assume was for a previous version of Ruby/Rails.  (Which I would place in my user model.)

```
validates_presence_of :password, :on => create
```

As the syntax for my password validation in my user model is different (below), I'm confused about the syntax I would need.

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true
```

I have searched other posts and sure could use some direction.

-- Disclaimer -- I did see that there is a screen cast about conditional validations but I'm not able to watch it at the moment.

Thanks, all.

Edit - inserted the following code and it does permit a user record update without complaining about the password field missing.

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :on => :create
```

Comment: Of course I (kind of) resolved this issue as soon as I posted my question.  However, I think my resolution (which I added at the bottom of my question) isn't a proper fix and I'll run into problems in the future when I begin changing passwords.

Comment: But how would this be handled if there is an update. Like you are doing something like a reset password or a change password?

Comment: @KevinHorvath -- Your question is outside of the scope of this topic. Did your search lead you here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend doing the following:

```
validates :password,
  :presence => true,
  :confirmation => true,
  :if => lambda{ new_record? || !password.nil? }
```

This basically says that a password needs to be confirmed on creation with password_confirmation and that it also needs to be confirmed when password is not nil - for example when the user is updating their password.

Comment: Thank you very much, Pan.  I commented out my most recent changes, added your code and then successfully updated a user record.  Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
validates :password, :presence => true, :confirmation => true, :on => :create
```

Read more on Railsguides: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on

Comment: Markus, as you can see (there's a bit of lag on my end regarding edits/comments) I ended up trying your solution as well.  Thanks!  And thanks for the link as well.