# How do I validate a password on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I validate a password field on 'create' and 'change' only.

And skip validation if it's empty on the update page meaning that the user doesn't want to change it?

Here's part of the form

```
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @account] do |f| %>
  <%= f.semantic_errors %>

  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation, :label => 'Confirm Password' %>
```

I've tried the answer here

[How do I exclude password fields from validation during record update? (Rails 3.0.4, Ruby 1.9.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572427/how-do-i-exclude-password-fields-from-validation-during-record-update-rails-3)

but it still checks when the password field is empty on update.

Comment: What authentication system do you use? Devise?

Comment: Yes. I'm new to the project though and is only familiar to the default Rails validation

Comment: It would be a way better, if you post what your controllers do, and what your models validate, as client side code doesn't do validation

Answer (score 0):

If you are using devise authentication system, you might want to check this one document:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip validations and callbacks maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572652/rails-3-skip-validations-and-callbacks) could help you...

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this:

```
validates :password, presence => true, :if => :password
```

This will skip at time of updation.

Comment: It's throwing an error (front end) since the password field is blank on update.

Comment: in all rails application or even in any application update password anad update fields are done on seprate pages so it will be better u do it on seprate pages means seprate functions